# Parsing json value with gson return null

Tags: android, json, gson

I tried the below code to generate json

```
        public void GenJson(){
            HostDetails hostDetails = new HostDetails();
            hostDetails.status = true;
            hostDetails.deviceAddedTime = "2018-02-07 05:44:21.196541";
            hostDetails.hostname = "MyHost";
            hostDetails.id = 1;

            Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().serializeNulls().create();
            JsonElement je = gson.toJsonTree(hostDetails);
            JsonObject jo = new JsonObject();
            jo.add(hostDetails.getClass().getSimpleName(), je);
            String jstr = jo.toString();
            System.out.println(jstr);
        }

        class HostDetails {
            public boolean status;
            public String deviceAddedTime;
            public String hostname;
            public int id;
        }
```

Generated Json output is

```
{
    "HostDetails":{
        "deviceAddedTime":"2018-02-07 05:44:21.196541",
        "hostname":"MyHost",
        "status":true,
        "id":1
    }
}
```

I want to convert above json data to class using Gson.  Below code i tried.  While debugging member of hostDetails1 class returns **null**.  How can i solve

```
public void GenClass(){
    Gson gson1 = new GsonBuilder().serializeNulls().create();
    HostDetails hostDetails1 = gson1.fromJson(jstr, HostDetails.class);
}
```

Comment: @cricket_007 Please explain more

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line is not necessary.

```
jo.add(hostDetails.getClass().getSimpleName(), je);
```

Neither is the `jo` variable.

You added an extra level to the JSON, where you can just create the JSON string right away in one line...

If you want to generate the correct JSON string, try

```
 Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().serializeNulls().create();

 String jstr = gson.toJSON(hostDetails);
 System.out.println(jstr);
```

---

### Reasons

With this line

```
gson1.fromJson(jstr, HostDetails.class);
```

Gson is expecting this

```
{
    "deviceAddedTime":"2018-02-07 05:44:21.196541",
    "hostname":"MyHost",
    "status":true,
    "id":1
}
```

If you want to parse the given JSON, you need another wrapper class

```
class Foo {
    public Foo() {}

    @SerializedName("HostDetails")
    public HostDetails hostDetails;
}
```

Then

```
HostDetails hostDetails1  = gson1.fromJson(jstr, Foo.class).hostDetails;
```

And you need a default no-arg constructor

```
    class HostDetails {

        public HostDetails() {}

        public boolean status;
        public String deviceAddedTime;
        public String hostname;
        public int id;
    }
```

Maybe some setters and getters, too.

Comment: I can't avoid root element  "HostDetails" in json.  So how can i create json with String jstr = gson.toJSON(hostDetails);

Comment: 1) Why not? 2) You already created it. I showed you how to parse it.

Comment: `gson.toJSON(object)` will take the object to a string without the root element. https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/UserGuide.md#object-examples

Comment: How to add root element to json with String jstr = gson.toJSON(hostDetails); line

Comment: You make `hostDetails` a completely separate object. Such as a `hostDetails = new Foo()` in the example code I provided.

Answer (score 0):

Try `getter/setters` ,and this approach .!

```
 class HostResponse{
     @SerializedName("HostDetails")
     HostDetails  hostDetails;
    }


class HostDetails {
            public boolean status;
            public String deviceAddedTime;
            public String hostname;
            public int id;
        }


 HostResponse hostResponse= new Gson().fromJson(json.toString(), HostResponse.class);
```